# Windows time keeps changing to a certain (incorrect) local time

Tags: windows-10, sync, time, clock, time-zone

My laptop (ThinkPad) was purchased in Germany, then I move to a different time zone. The time of Windows 10 keeps changing back to German time. It can be fixed by clicking "Sync now" but how can I avoid doing so every time after (re)booting?

Regarding the setting:

1. "Set time automatically" is ON
2. Time zone and region are correct and has never been changed even when the time is wrong

It might have something to do with the dual boot, by the other OS (Ubuntu) works perfectly regarding system time

Comment: Run `Get-WinSystemLocale` in PowerShell, what comes back?

Comment: @spikey_richie the correct region (not Germany)

Comment: It could be related to windows getting the time from BIOS and expecting it to be a different timezone. Unfortunately I don't know how to fix this on windows.

Comment: When the system is the incorrect time, what time zone, is the system configured to?  Do you have RTC enabled within Windows by chance?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: In Settings you need to set your location on the same page as you set regional settings. Regional setting is only about formatting dates etc. `Get-WinSystemLocale` returns formatting info. And in Control Panel - Date and Time - you set time zone.

Comment: @user1644677 "Country or region" is correct and was never changed.

Comment: @Ramhound updated.